# Unit testing module .run in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

In my main app module I have this lines:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  }])
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'SecurityService',
    function ($rootScope, $location, SecurityService) {
      SecurityService.Initialize();
  }]);
```

SecurityService is a factory type and I want to test call of this line:

```
SecurityService.Initialize();
```

Any ideas how to inject spy in it?